# Как в kafka определить кто подключен

Tags: apache-kafka

Добрый день.
Прошу подсказать имеется ли какая-то возможность посмотреть в kafka (может в zoookeerer) кто ее использует(подключен или т.п.)
Можно конечно смотреть что-то через ZooInspector, но там нет IP адресов или hostname и вычислить "негодяев" не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Инструмент**: Oracle Java Mission Control

**Настройки JMX в Kafka**: kafka.../config/jmx >> zookeeper_jmx.properties

В инструменте после подключения к IP:zookeeper_jmx_port, MBeanServer, вкладка MBean Browser > org.apache.ZooKeeperService , там в теории должны быть подключения.